# Removing special characters from string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup to scrape some html/xhtml webpages as follows:

```
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
tables_list = soup.find_all("table")
```

However, my output shows several special characters (e.g. Â â ) which I want to filter out. I think I am missing something with respect to decoding.

Could you please point me to what I might be missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `response.text` contains your response, and you want to filter out those special characters, what you can do is re-encode your string so as to retain only the ascii characters (and ignore the others) and then decode it again, like this (Python3):

```
In [7]: text = '<tag> normal text Â â˙∆¬˚∆ hello ©µµ </tag>'

In [8]: text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
Out[8]: '<tag> normal text   hello  </tag>'
```

Do this for `response.text`, and then you can continue with the rest of your processing.

Comment: @D.prd Cheers, glad to help. :)

Comment: @COLDSPEED, I am doing the ascii decoding as above but just realizing that my resultant text shows several unwanted characters such as '\xa0', '\r \r''. Am I missing something? Thanks.